# trying to make Node in its own .cpp and .h file

Tags: c++

i'm trying to put Node in it's own .cpp and .h files but i keeping get a similar error. i am trying to do this in a doubly linked list.

--errors--
In file included from z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\driver.cpp:3:
z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.h:25:9: error: 'Node::Node' names the constructor, not the type
         Node::Node* last;
         ^~~~

z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.h:26:9: error: 'Node::Node' names the constructor, not the type
         Node::Node* first;
         ^~~~

In file included from z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.cpp:1:
z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.h:25:9: error: 'Node::Node' names the constructor, not the type
         Node::Node* last;
         ^~~~

z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.h:26:9: error: 'Node::Node' names the constructor, not the type
         Node::Node* first;
         ^~~~

z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.cpp: In constructor 'List::List()':
z:\to cool for School\SDSU\CompE 260\Assignment #3\List.cpp:11:15: error: class 'List' does not have any field named 'first'
 List::List() :first(0), last(0)
               ^~~~~
-- list.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Node.h "
using namespace std;

#ifndef LIST
#define LIST


class List
{
    public:
        List(); // explixit constructor 
        ~List();

        bool empty(); // return true if the list is empty, otherwise return false
        void insertAtEnd(double& x); //insert a value x on the end of the list
        void del(double& x); //if value x is in the list, remove x
        void display(ostream& out) const; //Display the data values in the list in the order inserted
        double sum(); // Compute and return the sum of the values in the list -- we will sum as we add and delete as we remove
        double average(); // Compute and return the average of the values in the list


    private:/* data members */

        Node::Node* last;
        Node::Node* first;
        int numNodes=0;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const List& s);

#endif // !LIST
```

--node.h

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef NODE
#define NODE

class Node
{
    public:

        Node();//default constructor
        Node(Node* prevNodePtr,double value , Node* link);
        Node* getNext() const;
        double getData() const;
        Node* getPrev() const;
        void setData(double newData);
        void setPrev(Node* newPrev);
        void setNext(Node* newNext);
        //--- Node constructor
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------------
            Precondition:  None.
            Postcondition: A Node has been constructed with value in its data
                part and its next part set to link (default 0).
            -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Node(): data(0), prev(0), next(0){} //defuault constructor
        // Node(Node* prevNodePtr,double value , Node* link) //explicit value constructor 
        // {
        //     prev = prevNodePtr;
        //     data = value;
        //     next = link;
        // }
    private:
        double data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
};

#endif
```

Please help

Comment: The error messages seem pretty clear. The correct syntax is `Node* last;`, not `Node::Node* last;`

Comment: that fixed it , Thank you